# Failed to obtain the Json Web Token(JWT) for service principal id ' '. Exception Message: An error occurred while sending the request

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, tfs, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to create a pipeline using TFS and Azure Portal. I have created the build, but I couldn't create the release. I can't verify the connection. I've tried changing SP key expiry date. I've also assigned a role to the app. Does anyone know what is the issue?

This is the error I got
[image]

Comment: I'm facing the same issue

Comment: @Yenny - Have you got solution to the problem.